# IOS-Chrome: While scrolling screen getting freezed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

> 1) I am using material ui with react js.
>   i have added simple scollable code, when i reached at bottom of the screen/scroll, its freez.
>
> 2) i also try with simple html page, its working correctly.

```
    <div
        style={{
          height: 400,
          overflowY: "scroll",
          WebkitOverflowScrolling: "touch"
        }}
      >
        {Arr.map((rec, i) => {
          return <h1 key={i}>{rec}</h1>;
        })}
    </div>
```

Please let me know, what is wrong...

**Issue occured only on IOS chrome,**

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I got solution, by adding following code.

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", e => e.stopPropagation() );
```